# Different number of rows exporting a table to a csv file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have loaded a table in mysql (xampp) with around 40,000,000 rows, with it I created another table with around 6,000,000 rows and I exported it to a csv file using:

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION
(SELECT ...
FROM ctr_train0
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/.../file.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```

no errors, but this command creates a csv file with around 200,000 rows less than the original table, What happens? How can I export all the 6,000,000 rows?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess -- given the limited information -- is the use of `union`.  This removes duplicates from the output, and the duplicates are both *between* tables and *within* tables.  So, if your data has duplicates, this removes them.

Try running the query with `union all` instead:

```
(SELECT ...)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ...
FROM ctr_train0
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/.../file.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```